# Appium is failing to interact with react native elements for iOS, finding overlapped elements

Tags: react-native, appium, appium-ios

I have scripted appium code to click on an element on iOS native app, developed in react native.
I am able to get the element locator details using appium inspector but can see in the inspector that the actual element is overlapped by some other elements from previous screens.
So when I run a code though the appium can recognize the element, actual click is being received by invisible overlapped elements.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvIkX.png)
So I would like to understand the appium support for the react native apps.